# Azure Ad Authentication for Blazer pages not for the api

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a component (Solution) which has a bunch of API endpoints in a project, while in the same solution, I have a project for BlazerServer pages.

I want to Authenticate only the blazor pages using AzureAd Authentication, not the api endpoints. I have added the following to the program.cs

```
var scopes = new[] { "user.read" };

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
            {
                options.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
                options.TenantId = "xxxxx-1c2d-bv-9809-xxxxx";
                options.ClientId = "yyyyy-1a2b-397-877-yyyyyy
                options.ClientSecret = "SOME_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET";
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
            })
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(scopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta")
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
// By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
     options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

**BUT**
this is now redirecting all calls to the api endpoints to OpenId

How can I apply Authentication only to the Blazor pages (not to the api endpoints)

Comment: Hi, if you only want to have authentication for your blazor server app, then you only need to have `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();`. In  the meantime, what you have in your `Program.cs` should makes you sign in and then redirect to the blazor server page, what do you mean about `redirecting all calls to the api endpoints to OpenId`? could you pls have a screenshot for your issue?

Comment: In my solution in Visual Studio, I have mainly following two projects

1: project with different endpoints

Comment: The solution in visual studio has following two projects

1: project for Blazor pages

Comment: could you pls give us a screenshot of your solution explorer? and a screenshot about your issue, for example, you want to redirect back to server page `/fetchdata`, but it redirect to somewhere else?

Comment: The solution in visual studio has two projects 
1: project for Blazor pages 
2: project for api end points 

I was able to call following endpoint http://localhost:5000/api/abcendpoint 
where I do not need any authentication.

but right after the Azure Ad Auth implementation as soon as I enter localhost:5000/api/abcendpoint it redirects the call to login.microsoftonline.com/70123499-ad05-4222-7op0-e7142aa2f6c1/… profile offline_access user.read


I only want authentication on the blazor pages not on my api endpoints. Hope the quesiton is clear now?

Comment: thank you sir, it's clear. assuming I have 2 projects in one solution, one is blazor server have home page(localhost:4070) and an asp.net core web api project which has an API(localhost:5000/api/abcEndpoint). Assuming I call this api in my home page, and before I add AAD authentication in my blazor app, I can call this api and get response, If  I added AAD authentication in my blazor app but I didn't add `[Authorize]` attribute into `_Host.cshtml`, I can go to the home page and call this API as well. If I added this attribute in `_Host.cshtml`, I need to sign in first to visit any blazor page.

Comment: @TinyWang, you have even confused me now :(
Lets see if someone else has a suggestion on my question.

Comment: okay..let's see.

Comment: I posted an answer but removed it again because there seems to be an issue in the framework, see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39321

Answer (score 0):

As already posted in a comment, there seems to be an issue with the template in that it configures the application to authorize all incoming requests by default.

See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39321 to learn more.

The culprit here is this section generated by the template:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Just remove this section or at least the `options.FallbackPolicy` assignment. Then you will have all pages accessible.

Among various approaches you then have 2 options to enable auth on specific pages:

1. Enable auth by default and disable it for specific pages (recommended)

   - Put an `@attribute [Authorize]` in `_Imports.razor`
   - Put an `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` in any page where auth is not needed
2. Enable auth where necesssary

   - Put an `@attribute [Authorize]` in any page where auth is needed

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the issue I raised the question on. The solution was to introduce two different schemes for the authorization.

One for the openId (as I want to apply auth and authentication only on my blazor pages. I will have LoggedInUserPolicy as an attribute on the blazor page.) and the other "AllowAnonymous"  (as for the time being I do not want to impose any authentication / authorization on my api end points)

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {    
        AuthorizationPolicy defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddAuthenticationSchemes("default").RequireAssertion((a) => true).Build();
        AuthorizationPolicy loggedInUserPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();

        options.AddPolicy("AllowAnonymous", defaultPolicy);
        options.AddPolicy("OpenId", loggedInUserPolicy);
    });
```

It took a while but I solved it :D

Cheers

Qasim Raza